# Parsing a string to get the values of certain attributes

Tags: c#, beginner, strings, parsing

I have written a small method that extracts certain information from a string. An example of such a string is

```
"Some text BLA/123/5345/349230498 some more text PNR: 12345678, Name: John, CallName: Peter, TimeStamp: 01.10.2015"
```

Now I need certain information from this string, e.g. the `PNR`, `Name`, `CallName`, and `TimeStamp` (as `string`). Right now the method looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads the value of a specified attribute from the log entry.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="identifier">The prefix used in the string (e.g. "Name" in "Name: John").</param>
/// <returns>The value of the attribute (e.g. "John" bei "Name: John".</returns>
private string GetValueFromMessage(string identifier)
{
  int index = this.Message.IndexOf(identifier) + identifier.Length + 2;

  if (index != -1)
  {
    char c = this.Message[index];
    string result = string.Empty;

    while (c != ',')
    {
      result += c;
      index++;
      if (index < this.Message.Length)
      {
        c = this.Message[index];
      }
      else
      {
        break;
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Some parts that I don't like about my code, and don't know if they're done correctly:

- It looks too long/not elegant to me. Specifically, I think the loop could be done more efficiently. I tried different loops, also tried with a line of the form `c = this.Message[++index]`, but then I ran into problems at the end of the string.
- I want to get rid the double usage of `c = this.Message[index]` somehow.
- Is it even good style to `return null` if there is no occurrence of the attribute? (As info: this can happen, but maybe it would be smarter to return `string.Empty` then?)
- Should I use `this.Message` instead of just `Message` when it is a public property of the surrounding class?
- I also want to get rid of the `if` statement (and the ugly `break`) inside the loop if possible, but didn't really find a way yet.

Maybe something along the lines of

```
while (index < this.Message.Length && c != ',')
```

would work?

Comment: Why not use a regex to quickly extract the interesting part of the string, for example:  `( Name: )(.+?)(,)` for "Name" attribute ?

Comment: Can I ask why the data is in this format? A more structured string format like Json or Xml would make this task a breeze. Unless the point of this exercise is to learn how to parse strings...

Comment: @Dan Sure you can ;) The program I'm writing has to get log messages of a specific kind (employees quitting) from the Database and extract information about the 'request' that has been made regarding IT items (his equipment e.g.). Unfortunately, the log message format is more plain text than anything and I can't influence this, as there are several applications writing logs about this subject. Worse: they all differ in formatting...

Comment: @ShivanDragon Oh, that's a good idea as well, I'm going to have a look at this regex and try to understand it. It shouldn't be too hard, but I only came across regex's once so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should include the space before the identifier and the separator after the identifier, that way it will find the right identifier even if the string contains properties in a different order.

If the string contains for example `CallName: Peter, NameAlias: Johnny, Name: John` you would want the last property when looking for `Name` rather than the first property because it ends with `Name` or the value `"ias: Johnny"` from the second property.

(Including the space before the identifier naturally won't find an identifier if it starts at the first character of the string, but that doesn't seem to be the case with your data.)

You don't need a loop to find the end of the value, you can use `IndexOf` with a start index.

```
private string GetValueFromMessage(string identifier) {
  identifier = " " + identifier + ": ";
  int index = this.Message.IndexOf(identifier) + identifier.Length;

  if (index != -1) {
    int index2 = this.Message.IndexOf(",", index);
    if (index2 == -1) {
      index2 = this.Message.Length;
    }
    return this.Message.Substring(index, index2 - index);
  }

  return null;
}
```

Additionally, you can use `.IndexOf(identifier, 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` if you want to make a case insensetive match on the identifier.

---

Using `this.Message` or `Message` is a matter of convention, neither is clearly better than the other. While `this.Message` is more specific, `Message` should usually be clear enough, but you have to be a bit more careful when naming members to avoid conflicts, but on the other hand you should always avoid those conflicts anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you know your delimiters, you can use them to break up the input string into smaller strings.

```
string input = @"Some text BLA/123/5345/349230498 some more text PNR: 12345678, Name: John, CallName: Peter, TimeStamp: 01.10.2015";
string value = String.Empty;

List<string> keyValuePairs = input.Split(',').ToList();

foreach (var keyValuePair in keyValuePairs)
{
    string key = keyValuePair.Split(':')[0].Trim();
    if (key == "Name")
    {
        value = keyValuePair.Split(':')[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, I may not have been specific enough with what parameters I need from this string, but I think this won't work for the `PNR` part, will it? Because there's the whole text in front of it. But nevertheless, I think this could help me, because the `PNR` is a special case anyway because it has fixed length and I can get it more easily. +1 for the double split idea :)

Answer (score 2):

You could go more functional in style, working off the splitting as shown by Dan to get something like this. The resulting dictionary could also be factored out and reused to extract other values. (Note: You may want to use TryGetValue instead of ["xxxxx"] depending on your data).

```
        string input = @"Some text BLA/123/5345/349230498 some more text PNR: 12345678, Name: John, CallName: Peter, TimeStamp: 01.10.2015";

        var value = 
            input
            .Split(',')
            .Select(
                pair => pair.Split(':'))
            .ToDictionary(
                keyValue => keyValue[0].Trim(),
                keyValue => keyValue[1].Trim())
            ["Name"];
```

Comment: If you're going to that effort you may as well keep the dictionary instead of just getting the one field - and if you're doing that then how about replacing `.ToDictionary(keyValue => keyValue[0].Trim(),keyValue => keyValue[1].Trim())` with 
`.ToDictionary(keyValue => keyValue[0].Split(' ').Last(),keyValue => keyValue[1].Split(',')[0].Trim());` - that way you have all the fields taken care of including PNR.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a regex like this?

```
internal class Program
{
    private const string MyInputString = @"Some text BLA/123/5345/349230498 some more text PNR: 12345678, Name: John, CallName: Peter, TimeStamp: 01.10.2015";
    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(MyInputString, @"PNR: (?<pnr>.*), Name: (?<name>.*), CallName: (?<callname>.*), TimeStamp: (?<timestamp>.*$)");
            Console.WriteLine("PNR={0}, Name={1}, Callname={2}, Timestamp={3}", 
                              match.Groups["pnr"],
                              match.Groups["name"], 
                              match.Groups["callname"], 
                              match.Groups["timestamp"]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Add appropriate error handling here
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This will output:

> PNR=12345678, Name=John, Callname=Peter, Timestamp=01.10.2015